# Rails Time is not changing over the course of a Console Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on a Rails 3.2 application. We are running on Ruby 1.9.3 and Postgres 9.1.3. Most of the content on the site is organized by a published_at datetime stamp.  The public facing queries ask for content in relation to the Time.zone.now:

```
Post.where(["published_at <= ?", Time.zone.now])
```

Upon loading the console and asking for this post this query was generated:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (published_at <= '2013-02-25 16:32:19.852109')
```

And then 10 minutes later in the same Console session:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (published_at <= '2013-02-25 16:32:19.852109')
```

Notice that the time Rails is injecting into the query is not changing. If I run a local development session for a couple of hours, the timestamp Rails is injecting is always the same.

Also, I have tried swapping out Time.zone.now for Time.now and even Time.new, all with the same results.

Comment: Can you confirm that nothing has frozen time in the code? Such as using Timecop?

Comment: Not that I know of. I checked the Gemfile and Timecop, or anything with the word time in it, is not a dependency. There is no need for that type of functionality in this project.

Comment: is this code in a scope ?

Comment: Yes it is, would that cause a problem?

Comment: you have to wrap it in a lambda then. I'll show you in an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rewrite your scope like this :

```
scope :myscope, ->{ where(["published_at <= ?", Time.zone.now]) }
```

`Time.zone.now` appears "frozen" because the scope macro only gets executed **once** (when the class is loaded). Using a lambda prevents this.

Comment: in ruby 1.9+, it is equivalent to `lambda { # code }`. A lambda is a special kind of proc that is more strict on argument requirements. A proc is a bit of code that you can pass around, much like a block. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html